# Got me thinking or made me think?

Tags: phrases

What do you say?

1. got me thinking
2. made me think

Is there a difference between those two phrases?

I recently heard someone say *“it got me thinking”* — which got ***me*** thinking about whether it also *“made **me** think”.* ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on whether you are still thinking about the topic. If the act of thinking has been completed, then you would use "made me think." The other option, *got me thinking*, implies that the thinking hasn't ended, or that you are still in thought about this topic (every now and then).